# If theres multiple fragments after fragment remove from backstack, which method runs

Tags: android, android-fragments

If there's multiple fragments one on another, after one fragment remove from the stack, which method runs in the below fragment.

This is whats happens in the program,
Fragment A calls -> Fragment B

Then I remove Fragment B. So now its in the fragment A. I in that moment I want to run a method in Fragment A.

I tried onResume in Fragment A. But its not working. Can anyone please suggest a method to achieve this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [Callbacks](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) to communicate between fragments, or use broadcast receivers

To use callbacks...

In Fragment B declare an interface like so

```
 public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void myMethod();
 }
```

Also in fragment B create a global instance of our OnFragmentInteractionListener :

```
 private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
```

Then whenever you want the method in Fragment A to be called just use :

```
mListener.myMethod();
```

Now in Fragment A we need to provide the myMethod and implement our listener from Fragment B :

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements FragmentB.OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

And also in Fragment A provide the method

```
public void myMethod(){
 //Hello World
}
```

Comment: How does the below fragment knows the above fragment removed. Can callbacks used to identify that?

Comment: what is you want Fragment A to do ?

Comment: I have custom actionbar. Both fragment use same back button in that action bar. Each fragment I create onclick listener to that button. So after I moved to Fragment B and comes to Fragment A then I want to call Fragment A related onclick listener. Otherwise its still takes Fragment B's listener and crashes.

Comment: so make fragment A listener call the myMethod  too and then call it mListener.myMethod from fragment B back click listener

Comment: It gives null pointer exception when I tried your way. Are you sure above way is correct

Comment: can you show me the code you are using to replace fragments?